# .babelrcのpresets, pluginsが何を指しているか分かりません。

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, babeljs

Electronの勉強のため、
https://github.com/szwacz/electron-boilerplate
をcloneし、読んだり変更したりしているのですが、
このプロジェクトに含まれる、

https://github.com/szwacz/electron-boilerplate/blob/master/.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "browsers": "last 2 Chrome versions",
          "node": "current"
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [["transform-object-rest-spread", { "useBuiltIns": true }]]
}
```

の指している内容が分かりません。

https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/
も見ましたがよく分かりませんでした。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

babelの自体ではなく、個別のプラグインの設定なので[babel-preset-env](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-env/)と[transform-object-rest-spread](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/)にそれぞれ解説があります。

最新か1つ前のバージョンのChromeと今ビルドに使っているバージョンのNodeを対象にbabelで変換しています。